# Crash ERROR_CGDataProvider_BufferIsNotReadable + 12, CGDataProviderRetainBytePtr + 216

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a crash once in every 1000 to 2000 sessions in our app and I can't figure out what to do about it.

Is that an Apple iOS crash where I cant do anything about it?

I am using SDWebImage pod in my project, maybe it is that?

here is the crash log:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0  CoreGraphics                   0x182cfa59c ERROR_CGDataProvider_BufferIsNotReadable + 12
1   CoreGraphics                  0x000000018582e2c0 CGDataProviderRetainBytePtr + 216
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187f00048 CA::Render::(anonymous namespace)::create_image_from_image_data() + 196
3   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187efe1a0 CA::Render::create_image() + 900
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187f00e60 CA::Render::copy_image() + 472
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187f01228 CA::Render::prepare_image() + 20
6   QuartzCore                      0x00000001880101a8 CA::Layer::prepare_commit() + 332
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187f7245c CA::Context::commit_transaction() + 576
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187f99b90 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
9   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187f9a9d0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback() + 92
9
10   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f65edc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f63894 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e83e78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 468
13  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185d30f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
14  UIKit                           0x000000018d50367c UIApplicationMain + 236
15  GOTit                           0x0000000100bb8e10 main (main.m:18)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001839a056c start + 4

- Full crash report:

Thread 1 name:  gputools.smt_poll.0x1c003bba0
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c460c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001825dce90 usleep + 64
2   GPUToolsCore                    0x0000000104b75f0c
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 2 name:  gputools.smt_poll.0x1c003fa20
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c460c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001825dce90 usleep + 64
2   GPUToolsCore                    0x0000000104b75f0c
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a3568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5a308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b57ed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a77e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
4   Foundation                      0x00000001834ad594 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x00000001834cc9ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
6   UIKit                           0x000000018cd367b8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
7   Foundation                      0x00000001835af0f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 4 name:  GAIThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a3568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5a308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b57ed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a77e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
4   Foundation                      0x00000001834ad594 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x00000001834ff56c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
6   GOTit                           0x00000001033626fc
7   Foundation                      0x00000001835af0f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a3568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5a308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b57ed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a77e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
4   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183367128 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 780
5   Foundation                      0x00000001835af0f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a3568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5a308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b57ed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a77e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
4   GOTit                           0x00000001031af888
5   Foundation                      0x00000001835af0f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c40f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000181d7bea4 std::__1::condition_variable::wait() + 24
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189f1bf2c std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >() + 96
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189f1be54 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 172
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189f1c1b8 std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >() + 44
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a3568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5a308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b57ed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a77e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
4   WebCore                         0x000000018a9e8a34 RunWebThread() + 560
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c460c __semwait_signal + 8
1   Foundation                      0x00000001835ae2a8 +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 136
2   GOTit                           0x000000010316dd2c
3   Foundation                      0x00000001835af0f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d82b4 _pthread_body + 308
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d8180 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b74 thread_start + 4


Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a35a4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9dc0c
2   GOTit                           0x0000000102ba8290
3   GOTit                           0x0000000102ba8810
4   GOTit                           0x0000000102b135c8
5   GOTit                           0x00000001028c4888
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
7   GOTit                           0x0000000102b13b8c
8   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
9   GOTit                           0x0000000102b14be8
10  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
11  GOTit                           0x0000000102a785c8
12  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
13  GOTit                           0x0000000102a7cdbc
14  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
15  GOTit                           0x0000000102b81444
16  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
17  GOTit                           0x0000000102ba5354
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181df6ef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass() + 148
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181e04638 objc_destructInstance + 88
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181e04690 object_dispose + 16
21  GOTit                           0x0000000102bac7e8
22  CFNetwork                       0x00000001832edff4 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.207 + 76
23  Foundation                      0x0000000183589ba0 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
24  Foundation                      0x00000001834c9894 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
25  Foundation                      0x00000001834b94c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa19e4
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa19e4
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa18a4
31  Foundation                      0x000000018358b878 __NSOQSchedule_f + 376
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa2678
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa0f08
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa69d0
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa66f4
37  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d706c _pthread_wqthread + 1268
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826a35a4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9dc0c
2   GOTit                           0x0000000102ba8290
3   GOTit                           0x0000000102ba8810
4   GOTit                           0x0000000102b135c8
5   GOTit                           0x00000001028c4888
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
7   GOTit                           0x0000000102b13b8c
8   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
9   GOTit                           0x0000000102b14be8
10  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
11  GOTit                           0x0000000102a785c8
12  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
13  GOTit                           0x0000000102a7cdbc
14  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
15  GOTit                           0x0000000102b81444
16  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001825cfa60 _Block_release + 160
17  GOTit                           0x0000000102ba5354
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181df6ef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass() + 148
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181e04638 objc_destructInstance + 88
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181e04690 object_dispose + 16
21  GOTit                           0x0000000102bac7e8
22  CFNetwork                       0x00000001832edff4 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.207 + 76
23  Foundation                      0x0000000183589ba0 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
24  Foundation                      0x00000001834c9894 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
25  Foundation                      0x00000001834b94c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa19e4
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa19e4
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa18a4
31  Foundation                      0x000000018358b878 __NSOQSchedule_f + 376
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa2678
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa0f08
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa69d0
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa66f4
37  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d706c _pthread_wqthread + 1268
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b68 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b68 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 14:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181e04614 objc_destructInstance + 52
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a98f04
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a972a0
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa3d9c
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a987ec
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa4f6c
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aac020
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c460c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182645f34 sleep + 44
2   GOTit                           0x00000001028c21f4
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a952cc
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa3f80
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a987ec
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa4f6c
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aac020
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c460c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182645f34 sleep + 44
2   GOTit                           0x00000001028c21f4
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a952cc
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa3f80
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a987ec
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa4f6c
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aac020
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b68 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c460c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182645f34 sleep + 44
2   GOTit                           0x00000001028c21f4
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a952cc
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa3f80
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a987ec
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa4f6c
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aac020
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c3e5c __open + 8
1   Foundation                      0x00000001834c6be8 _NSReadBytesFromFileWithExtendedAttributes + 132
2   Foundation                      0x00000001835405a8 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:maxLength:error:] + 184
3   Foundation                      0x00000001834cb6ec +[NSData(NSData) dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:] + 68
4   GOTit                           0x0000000102f181dc
5   GOTit                           0x0000000102f18780
6   GOTit                           0x0000000102f18eb0
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a952cc
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a9528c
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa3f80
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104a987ec
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aa4f6c
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000104aac020
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 24:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b68 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 27:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b68 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 28:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b68 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 29:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 30:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826c4d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827d6b6c start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem, there is a thread here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94163 but there are no solutions yet

Comment: Also seeing this and using SDWebImage, don't know if it's related. Seeing this exclusively on iOS 11.2.x

Comment: I've have the same crash reported, but I am not using SDWebImage...

Comment: yup. same crashing behaviour.... not reproducible... maybe some AB test apple is running?!?

Comment: +1 Facing the same issue. It's our top crash, and only on iOS 11.2+. We're using SDWebImage & Texture for loading images.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you guys using Realm to store the images by any chance? cc @SiddharthGupta

Comment: @hyouuu We're using Realm, but not to store images.

Comment: @SiddharthGupta do you store thumbnails in Realm? Could this be caused by https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/3005?

Comment: I don’t use realm in my project.

Comment: We have this problem in our app and don't use SDWebImage or Realm. We do a lot of image and video processing and use CoreGraphics and AVFoundation a lot. We use SDAVAssetExportSession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chris-garrett pointed me in the right direction and I was able to greatly mitigate the issue by fixing memory leaks.

Users who are now getting this error are people who spend at least 30 minutes on the app, which is pretty uncommon. Also, the fact that it affects mostly big screens like iPhone 7/6s/8 Plus, iPhone X, where more memory is needed to render images would corroborate that theory

---

What you should do to solve this, is to check the memory while debugging. If it increases gradually when repeating the same actions, there's certainly something for you to fix.

[image]

There are many ways to find leaks in your app, I'm not a big fan of Instruments, but you can find many tutorials online if needed. Another option is to use memory graph. I wrote previously an article on how to use memory graph [here](https://medium.com/@stremsdoerfer/understanding-memory-leaks-in-closures-48207214cba).

Comment: I had found a really great leak and solving it had completely eliminated this crash!

Comment: Now my app has 1 crash in 10,000 sessions! have more than 6000 sessions a day.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same thing.  Here's some additional info.

This crash happens after my app captures an image, crops it, and rescales it.

The crash info showed that the user only had 6% memory available.

I suspect that something in my image processing pipeline fails silently, possibly due to running out of memory, and then produces a corrupt UIImage.  Then when I try to draw it it crashes.

In my case I added a bunch of guards and logging statements so that when the crash happens again I'll hopefully get more info and be able to post a workaround.

Comment: Ok please update us as soon as you have new information.

Comment: My case too: I capture an image, color-correct it and crop it. Then I render a thumbnail of it. The following code fails with the error:

    let image = renderer.image { (context) in
    self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
    }

Comment: I want to add that this error happens mostly on 7 Plus